# Unable to access public api on aws api gateway from app running on an ec2 behind vpc

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-api-gateway

I have an created a public aws api gateway which i have have tested and works with an app deployed on my local and with curl

But when i deploy the app on the ec2 on a vpc it cannot query that public api i get 403 forbidden

Is there any reason as to why i cannot query this api ?

From more debugging i did i created another private api which i can access from the ec2 behind the vpc and everything works fine

I also tried running some curl requests to another public api and that works

It seems my issue is with when access public regional aws api gateway from a vpc

Comment: Where is your instance, public subnet?

Comment: @Marcin its in eu-west-1

Comment: I mean in VPC, private subnet, public subnet? If private, do you have internet gateway and nat gateway set up correctly?

Comment: @Marcin my bad its private with both and internet gateway and a nat gateway set up i don't think these are issues as i can run this curl command curl -v http://www.example.com/

Comment: so you should be able to curl your api endpoint. Hopefully you don't have vpc interface endpoint as well?

Comment: @Marcin i dont have a vpc interface endpoint but i still cant curl to that public api still getting 403 {"message":"Forbidden"}

Comment: The fact that you getting 403 it means you are connecting to it. So it must be something with with the call itself (wrong url?) or your api setup.

Comment: @Marcin I dont think its my api setup because it work fine everywhere else except when behind the vpc

Comment: @Marcin i think this could be it but i have just noticed in vpcs i can see there is an endpoint configured with *.<urlname> as part of the dns names could this be messing with the request some how

Comment: Could you clarify your setup. I undestand that  you have EC2 instance in a VPC. From the instance you are curling your regional api? But what do you mean when you write "another private api"? There is big difference between regional, edge and private API gateway endpoints.

Comment: If you have VPC interface endpont for api gateway in your VPC, you can't access regional nor edge API.

Comment: @Marcin i didn't know this existed till now someone else must have created it i guess all i have to do now is remove the *.<urlname> and change it to a more specified url that doesn't capture the url of the api

Comment: You can't change the url of the vpc interface endpoint. It shouldn't be there if you want to use regional API. If the VPC is important, try setting up second VPC for tests without the endpoint and see how it goes.

Comment: @Marcin Thanks for the help. For now i am just going to leave it as it is and use the private api with the app as it can access that api and regional api isn't needed now

Comment: No problem. If you don't mind I will post an answer for future reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comments, the issue was that the access to regional API was blocked by the VPC interface gateway. As explained [here](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/api-gateway-vpc-connections/) the presence of the gateway is going to block the access to regional and edge APIs.

The solution for now is to use [private API gateway endpoint](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-basic-concept.html#apigateway-definition-private-api-endpoint):

> An API endpoint that is exposed through interface VPC endpoints and
>   allows a client to securely access private API resources inside a VPC.
>   Private APIs are isolated from the public internet, and they can only
>   be accessed using VPC endpoints for API Gateway that have been granted
>   access.

Answer (score 1):

You may be running into the issue described here

https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/api-gateway-vpc-connections/